# $SU(n)$ and a free group of rank $2$

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

So it was mentioned to me that the special unitary contains a free group of rank $2$ in it and its related to the Banach Tarski paradox, but I can't find any references to this. Can someone provide a brief explanation how the two are related and a sketch of how this result is proven, or even better point to me to some references which proves this in detail. Thanks.

Comment: See, for example, https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/09/17/that-trick-where-you-embed-the-free-group-into-a-lie-group/.

Comment: The key concept to look into here is amenability.